# Estimated # Rows way off, causing sort to spill to tempdb

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization

I'm trying to tune a long-running query and I suspect that the main reason for its poor performance is that the plan is littered with sort operations that are all spilling into tempdb. I think that I've traced this back to the estimated vs. actual row counts being way off in one of the early steps. Here's the part I'm looking at in the query plan. Note the estimated rows (122.8) vs actual (43590), and in the next step a Sort with a warning icon on it.

[image: Figure 1]

I've already tried:

- Updating statistics with fullscan
- Creating statistics on (AssessmentID, Points, Percentile, MasteryLevel)
- Creating statistics on (AssessmentID) where (Points is null and Percentile is null and MasteryLevel is null)

But none of these things has improved the estimated number of rows. What do I need to do to improve this estimate? Am I on the right track in thinking that this is the cause for the spill into tempdb?

Comment: You could just materialise that step into a temp table so SQL Server knows exactly how many rows come from that join then join onto the temp table instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is supposed to be a queryable view, so temp tables are not a good fit in this case.